# How to change the text being inputted turn to '*' in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do I change the text to * while it is being inputted, like:

```
#Think that the code below is running in the console and I am 
#inputting in it

Password: Example # How do make it turn it to '*******' while it is still being written?
```

Yup, i am not forced to only input, I can type in any command, please just tell me how to.

And you can tell tk code too

Comment: Why does this have the `tkinter` tag? Are you wanting to get the input from a window, or from the console?

Comment: Accidently added that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tkinter entry, use the option `show`. Here is a code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
passw = tk.Entry(root,show="*")
passw.grid(row=0,column=0)
passb = tk.Button(root,text="Print Password",command=lambda :print(passw.get()))
passb.grid(row=1,column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

---

To get password in **console**, you will have to modify the module `getpass` <sup>*(Try at your own risk)*</sup>. Go to your python folder and open folder `Lib`. Open the file `getpass.py` and go to line `98` (there will be a function naming `win_getpass`)
Replace the whole function (`win_getpass`) with (lines:98-119) <sup>*(Updated)*</sup>:

```
def win_getpass(prompt='Password: ', stream=None,show=""):
    """Prompt for password with echo off, using Windows getch()."""
    if sys.stdin is not sys.__stdin__:
        return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)

    for c in prompt:
        msvcrt.putwch(c)
    pw = ""
    while True:
        c = msvcrt.getwch()
        if c == '\r' or c == '\n':
            break
        if c == '\003':
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        if c == '\b':
            pw = pw[:-1]
            if pw != "":msvcrt.putwch("\b");msvcrt.putwch(" ");msvcrt.putwch("\b")
        else:
            pw = pw + c
            msvcrt.putwch(show)
    msvcrt.putwch('\r')
    msvcrt.putwch('\n')
    return pw
```

Now you can use the getpass function as:

```
import getpass
getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ",show="*")
```

You can change the value of `show` to whatever you want to show. Default is empty (means hide).

#### Note:

`getpass` will only work in console. It will raise error in IDLE.

Screenshot:

[image: console]

Comment: `getpass()` does not echo `*`.

Comment: A monkey-patched standard library is not portable. This monkey-patch is Windows only.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I know its for windows only but it works.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I have added only single line. `msvcrt.putwch(show)` which prints the argument taken from the function.

Comment: It is doing the same as it was doing previosly.

Comment: @TejasJoshi Make sure you have saved the file correctly, Also its for console. Its possible that you might be running it in IDLE.

Comment: @BlackThunder I've saved it correctly and still it's not working.

Comment: @TejasJoshi Can you let me see the terminal in which you ran it?

Comment: Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import get pass
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getpass(prompt='password: ', show='*')

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Tejas Joshi\Desktop\My folder\Programs\Python 3.6\lib\getpass.py", line 100
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
password: example
'example'
>>>

Comment: well, I just copy pasted it.

Comment: @TejasJoshi. I understood the problem. You have to run it in console not IDLE.

Comment: well, it niether run in the console nor the IDLE.

Comment: @TejasJoshi Can you make and share me a video like I did?

Comment: I found the problem. I can say that you have not followed my instructions correctly. First of all , don't open the module directly from python IDLE. It will not open the default path to the file. Open the file manually and then edit it. Second the getpass module don't works in IDLE. Its only for console. Here is a video to guide you: https://streamable.com/bsks9

Comment: @TejasJoshi Are you sure the python folder you opened is the path to your original python? Navigate to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python` and see if the python folder is there. I will look for backspace. Backspace works in background but don't remove `*`.

Comment: @TejasJoshi I have added the backspace functionality in the code.

Comment: Yeah it was the correct path. I had changed the path to this folder in the installer.

Comment: @TejasJoshi Yes, I work on a laptop. You can accept my answer.

Answer (score 3):

use the  [getpass](https://pymotw.com/3/getpass/) module -

```
import getpass
getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")
```

Comment: `getpass()` does not echo `*`.

Comment: true! it is even safer since it is not showing the number of characters in the password

Comment: Yes, but it's not what the question asks. Also, I've always found the security argument unconvincing. When I log on to my OS or my bank's website or Stackoverflow it echoes a dummy character.  It's pretty universal except for the terminal.